# Persist filter values in codeigniter with pagination library

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I use the default codeiginter pagination library. I tried implementing this in a previously created page which shows all vacancies, but since we are getting TOO many on the site, the performance is terrible. This is why I need pagination on this page. Note that this is not the cleanest solution, there is a new track going on which overhauls the entire page and starts from scratch. This is a quick & dirty solution because we need to keep it working on our live environment until the rework is done.

This is the controller code I have:

```
public function overviewVacancies($city = null)
{
    $this->is_logged_in();

    // Load Models
    $this->load->model('vacancy/vacancies_model');
    $this->load->model('perk/interests_model');
    $this->load->model('perk/engagement_model');
    $this->load->model('user/userSavedVacancies_model');

    // Passing Variables
    $data['title'] = lang("page_title_activities_overview");
    $data['description'] = lang('meta_desc_activities');
    $data['class'] = 'vacancy';
    $data['engagements'] = $this->engagement_model->getAll();
    $data['interests'] = $this->interests_model->getAllInterests();
    $data['bread'] = $this->breadcrumbmanager->getDashboardBreadcrumb($this->namemanager->getDashboardBreadName("0"), $this->namemanager->getDashboardBreadName("1"));
    $data['tasks'] = $this->interests_model->getAllTasks();

    // Set session data
    $this->session->set_userdata('previous',"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
    $this->session->set_userdata('previous-title', "1");

    $filterdata = array(
        'interests' => $this->input->post('interests'),
        'skills' => $this->input->post('skills'),
        'fulldate' => $this->input->post('daterange'),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
        'city' => $this->input->post('sublocality_level_1'),
        'capital' => $this->input->post('locality')
    );
    if (!empty($filterdata['interests'])) {
        $filterdata['interests'] = rtrim($filterdata['interests'], ";");
        $filterdata['interests'] = str_replace(' ', '', $filterdata['interests']);
        $filterdata['interests'] = str_replace(';', ',', $filterdata['interests']);
    }
    if (!empty($filterdata['skills'])) {
        $filterdata['skills'] = str_replace(' ', '', $filterdata['skills']);
        $filterdata['skills'] = explode(",", $filterdata['skills']);
    }
    //Manually clear the commune and city variables if the location was empty
    if (empty($filterdata['location'])) {
        $filterdata['city'] = '';
        $filterdata['capital'] = '';
    }

    if($city == null){
        $orgId = $this->organization_model->getOrgIdByName(LOCATION);
    }
    else{
        $orgId = $this->organization_model->getOrgIdByName($city);
        $data['bread'] = $this->breadcrumbmanager->getLocalBreadcrumb($this->namemanager->getDashboardBreadName("0"), $city, $data['title'], $data['vacancydetails']);
    }

    //Set the location to the subdomain automatically (e.g. when the link is clicked) so the activities of that subdomain only show up
    if (!empty(LOCATION)) {
        $data['title'] = sprintf(lang('page_title_local_activities'), ucwords(LOCATION));
        $data['description'] = sprintf(lang('meta_desc_local_activities'), ucwords(LOCATION));
        $filterdata['location'] = LOCATION;
        $data['bgcolor'] = $this->localSettings_model->getBgColorHexValueForOrgId($orgId->org_id);
    }

    if (!empty($filterdata['fulldate'])) {
        $splitfromandto = explode(" - ", $filterdata['fulldate']);
        $filterdata['datefrom'] = $splitfromandto[0];
        $filterdata['dateto'] = $splitfromandto[1];
    } else {
        $filterdata['datefrom'] = null;
        $filterdata['dateto'] = null;
    }

    //Put these variables in the data variable so we can prefill our filters again with the previous values
    //This is necessary because we don't use AJAX yet
    $data['filterdata'] = $filterdata;

    //Pagination : We do it here so we can re-use the filter query to count all our results
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $data['all_vacancies'] = $this->vacancies_model->getFilteredVacancies($filterdata);
    $pagconfig['base_url'] = base_url().VACANCY_OVERVIEW;
    $pagconfig['total_rows'] = count($data['all_vacancies']);
    $pagconfig['per_page'] = 1;
    $pagconfig['uri_segment']  = 2;
    $pagconfig['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($pagconfig);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $start = max(0, ( $this->uri->segment(2) -1 ) * $pagconfig['per_page']);

    //This variable contains all the data necessary for a vacancy to be displayed on the vacancy overview page
    $data['vacancies'] = $this->vacancies_model->getFilteredVacancies($filterdata, false, null, false, null, false, false, $pagconfig['per_page'], $start);

    // Template declaration
    $partials = array('head' => '_master/header/head', 'navigation' => '_master/header/navigation_dashboard', 'content' => 'dashboard/vacancy/overview', 'footer' => '_master/footer/footer');
    $data['vacancygrid'] = $this->load->view('dashboard/vacancy/vacancygrid', $data, TRUE);
    $this->template->load('_master/master', $partials, $data);
}
```

As you can see in the code i keep a variable called $filterdata, this contains all data which is used in our filters, since we don't use AJAX in this version, we need to pass it to the view every time to fill it up again and present it to the visitor. 
However, using pagination this breaks because it just reloads my controller method and thus the values in $filterdata are lost.

How do I go about this?

Note: it does not have to be a clean solution, it just needs to work since this page is going offline in a couple of weeks anyway.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you giving back the filter values to the view to keep in hidden fields and give back to the controller when you post back a new page number?

Comment: Hi ourmandave! I use the filter values to pre-fill the filters in my view (these are not hidden), and when the visitors submits again (or changes something) these values get sent back via post

Comment: Is it that the filter fields outside the pagination form and not getting submitted back?

Comment: I just use the default pagination by codeigniter library, it is on the same view, i don't resubmit the search form, but I click on the pagination number, so the controller method reloads, but the $filterdata variable is not passed through but made empty

Comment: Did some digging and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933232/3585500). The problem is pagination just creates links with posting back filter fields. The recommendation is to use GET instead of POST and pass a query string in the URL.